# TensorFlow: Available C++ equivalents of Python functions

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I would like to know how I can find the C++ equivalents for the TensorFlow methods widely used in Python. For example, where can find the equivalent of `tf.matmul()`? Is it available at all?

I was reading the [main.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc) in the [label_image](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image) example, and I noticed that it uses functions like `Sub()` and `Div()`, whose documentations I cannot find in the C++ API docs. I wonder where these functions come from.

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

This confusion is very much solved with the good documentation of the new [TensorFlow r1.0 C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update*: The answer is mostly meaningful for pre-1.0 versions of TensorFlow. MBA points to some new explanation provided by the TF team directly (official docs), and there was good refactoring around the ops :-)

---

The Python API delegates execution to C++ implementation for many operations.

The source code under `tensorflow/core/ops` contains kernels and ops. They are the actual operations that process commands invoked through the different APIs.

Kernels and ops follow a pattern. The `REGISTER_OP` macro "attaches" a C++ function implementation to a handle (a string) that gets invoked at runtime by one of the APIs. Such kind of architecture has its merits and drawbacks---out of scope here :-)

For example `tf.matmul`, the code can easily be found in `tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc` in the [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v0.12.0/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc). The typical pattern looks like:

```
REGISTER_OP("MatMul")
    .Input("a: T")
    .Input("b: T")
    .Output("product: T")
    .Attr("transpose_a: bool = false")
    .Attr("transpose_b: bool = false")
    .Attr("T: {half, float, double, int32, complex64, complex128}")
    .SetShapeFn(shape_inference::MatMulShape)
.Doc("[Edited: some doc string.]");
```

Where the actual code run to execute `tf.matmul` is in the function `shape_inference::MatMulShape` (the "functor" namely, a C++ function). Wrappers (for example the Python API) call the `MatMul` handle to execute the code.

Comment: It seems to be more clear in the documentation of the new r1.0 version: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/

Comment: Indeed ! Thank you for the link and your question update. I'll update the answer accordingly.